# How to get only n records from n tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables with different content which all have `datetime` column.

I want to get last 10 records by datetime DESC from any of 3 tables.

Maybe 5 records from table 1, 3 records from table2, and 2 records from table3

How can I do that in mysql. Should I use `Union` ?

I tried both these queries:
Query1:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*, table3.* FROM table1, table2, table3 LIMIT 10
```

Query2:

```
( SELECT * FROM table 1 LIMIT 10 )
UNION
( SELECT * FROM table 2 LIMIT 10 )
UNION
( SELECT * FROM table 3 LIMIT 10 )
```

but these queries returns 30 records.

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: I tried union, but it returns last 10 records from each table separately. 30 records it returns.

Comment: Try to `LIMIT` the number of result of each query

Comment: how can I limit to get 10 records from 3 tables ? 3.3 for each one !!!!?

Comment: No, limit each query, add the query you've tried in your question

Comment: Unions require the same number of columns in each connected query and the same format of each column. If the tables have "different content" as you say then most likely you don't want to use unions. You probably want 3 different queries. You can always bring them back on the same page with php.

Comment: Do your tables all have the same columns?

Comment: no, they are 3 different tables.

Answer (score 2):

you have to write separately as you need separate limit

**(IF having same columns)**

```
SELECT * FROM table1 limit 5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2 limit 3
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table3 limit 2
```

UPDATE:

```
//if we need 10 rows in the result
SELECT * FROM table1,table2,table3 limit 10
```

Comment: He said that the tables have "different content", unions require the same number of columns to be returned by each connected query, and for each of the columns to be of the same type. If the 3 tables have different content and you select all of the columns in each of the 3 connected queries like this, why do you think it would work?

Comment: he said content not columns,and also he said that he tried UNIONS in his question :)